# Obtaining travel insurance without permanent residency

Tags: insurance, nomad

I am looking to get full comprehensive travel (+ medical) insurance for my upcoming trip to Kenya. I have been looking around and comparing the various insurance companies

but I keep running into the same problem; *each provider requires a permanent residency.*

I have been a full-time traveler for almost two years and **I do not have any permanent residency or address.**

I am a Dutch citizen but I gave up my residency there last year. After Kenya I'm moving to Austria but I am not yet a resident there. I have also lived in Ireland for over a decade so I'm entitled to Irish citizenship (my mother is also Irish) but again, I don't have an address there and so do not have residency there either.

**How do I go about obtaining travel insurance without a permanent residency?**

Perhaps there is an insurance company specifically aimed at people like me?

Comment: Do you have provision for general medical care in some country? Travel insurance is generally priced on the assumption that you are getting most of your care some other way, usually in your country of residence.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan when I gave up my residency in the Netherlands access to the national medical care also got revoked. Maybe I'm entitled to it in Ireland although I'm not sure since I haven't lived there since 2015.

Comment: The European health care programs I'm aware of cover residents, not citizens.  I doubt Ireland's is different, especially considering how many Irish citizens live abroad.

Answer (score 2):

Travel insurance is usually linked to a limited length of travel. In case of insurance claims, the insurer might ask you for evidence of leaving your *home country*. You'll also find it difficult to find travel insurance policies that last longer than a year.

What you're looking for is probably something like a full health insurance. The cheaper ones may also come with a time limit but a significantly longer one. Try adding keywords like "expat" or "long-term" to your search.

An address, however, probably is still required and reading the policy is essential. Even with a non-travel health insurance insurers may put limits on how long you can "travel" to certain countries and create loopholes in their policies that could make your claims void.